# Ошибка: undefined reference to "num"

Tags: c, переменные, линковка

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int sum = 100;

int main()
{
    extern int sum;
    printf("Sum is %d \n", sum);
    extern int num;
    printf("Num is %d \n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Пытаюсь скомпилировать выдает вот это:

> C:\Users\1F43~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwBZIh0.o:global_1.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `num' collect2.exe: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1

Answer (score 3):

Этим

```
extern int num;
```

вы дали понять компилятору, что память под переменную выделять не надо - она определена где-то еще (как произошло, например, с переменной `sum` в вашем же примере).

А этого "где-то еще" не оказалось, так что линковщик так и не нашел, как разрешить ссылку на это имя...

В вашей программе достаточно просто определить переменные как локальные:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum = 100;
    printf("Sum is %d \n", sum);
    int num = 200;
    printf("Num is %d \n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

(переменную `num` нужно инициализировать каким-то значением, иначе она будет содержать мусор).

Comment: Я если честно только начал изучать программирование по книге Майка МакГрата  если не трудно укажите в моём коде ошибку и как должно быть в идеале

Comment: Я добавил код в ответ. Но я же не знаю, что именно вы изучаете - статические переменные, внешнее связывание или что-то еще... Поэтому мой код **с дидактической точки зрения** может быть некорректным